# Can I set different edition for top variable in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I know I can set different value in different resource file for one item, you can see Code A, Code B and Code C.

I hope to do the same work for top variable, just like Code D and Code E, can I do that?

**Code A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isProVersion">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**Code B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isProVersion">true</bool>
</resources>
```

**Code C**

```
build.gradle
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "info.dodata.voicerecorder"
        }

        pro {
            applicationId "info.dodata.voicerecorder.pro"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code D**

```
package info.dodata.voicerecorder.bll

import android.content.Context

var name="Hello For Free"
```

**Code E**

```
package info.dodata.voicerecorder.bll

import android.content.Context

var name="Hello For Pro"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the value of the `name` variable? You can simply use a string resource, same as you do with your boolean resource `isProVersion`.

so in Code A, add

```
<string name="appname">Free Version Name</string>
```

and in Code B add

```
<string name="appname">Pro Version Name</string>
```

Change Code D/E to

```
var name = getString(R.string.appname)
```

**Alternative solution using code sets**

You can use additional code sets per flavor. This would allow you to have different texts for the same field variable.

1. Find your project's `src` folder. It contains folders `main`, `test`, `androidTest`.
2. Create additional folders `free` and `pro`. These can now provide additional source codes that are only used for the specific flavor.
3. In `free`, create folder structure `java/info/dodata/voicerecorder/bll`.
4. In the bll folder, create a file Foo.java:

   ```
   package dodata.voicerecorder.bll;

   public class Foo {
       public final static String NAME = "Free Version Name";
   }
   ```
5. Do the same for the `pro` folder; same folder structure, same Foo.java but with slightly different code:

   ```
   package dodata.voicerecorder.bll;

   public class Foo {
       public final static String NAME = "Pro Version Name";
   }
   ```

Now you can use dodata.voicerecorder.bll.Foo.NAME everywhere in your code. When building an app flavor, the compiler will use the file from the folder, matching the flavor name. You can read up on this here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build

**Alternative solution using BuildConfig**

In your build.gradle file find your productFlavors section and specify an additional BuildConfig field like so:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_NAME', '"Free Version Name"'
    }
    pro {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_NAME', '"Pro Version Name"'
    }
}
```

In your code, you can now use the static string `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` that will give you the correct name for the flavor you're building.

Comment: Thanks! but I hope to do it at top function, you know, I can't use `context` in `ViewModel`, so I can't access string resource in `ViewModel`.

Comment: You can make your ViewModel extend AndroidViewModel. This gives you access to context.

Comment: Thanks! I see I can use `context` for access string resource  in `AndroidViewModel`, but I hope to do it att top function, can I do that ?

Comment: I added an alternative solution using source sets. If that is too much overhead, there would be yet another solution using additional BuildConfig fields.